# Robust method to detect pinpricks in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I expose films in a jig with pin pricks as reference markers. I use these references to register the scanned images of the film to other data.

I've been using mouse click coordinates to date, but I need to automate it and can't find a robust way to detect the pin pricks using binary image processing. I've tried various approaches using opencv with python (see below).

I don't use dust removal when scanning, that might be the issue, but it must be possible to distinguish the round pinpricks from dust no?

Does anyone have advice on suitable methods for detecting features like these pin pricks?

Thank you.

[image: The film image input]

Here's an example image which I want to process. There are 10 pin pricks and 1 dark area of exposure. I just want the coordinates of the pinpricks.

[image]

An example attempt of binary thresholding followed by erosion and dilation. It doesn't robustly remove noise instead of the features regardless of parameters.

[image]

An attempt at finding contours which still misses pinpricks and picks up noise.

[image]

An attempt at using a Hough Transform with a similar result

**** EDIT ****

My attempts at template matching using an example pinprick

[image]

This picks out all the pins with a threshold of 0.5. This works well as the template pinprick was taken from this image.

[image]

This is run on a different image to the template and struggles. At the same threshold.

[image]

The above match when run with a lower threshold. It picks out dust instead of pins.

```
threshold = 0.7 
templates_dir = '[Path to template images]' 
templates = []
#templ_shapes = []

# load the input image and template image from disk, then grab the
# template image spatial dimensions
print("[INFO] loading images...")
image = cv2.imread(scan_filename)
#image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_180)

for nt in range(1,100):
    templates.append(cv2.imread(templates_dir + "{}.tif".format(nt)))
    #templ_shapes.append(templates[nt-1].shape[:: -1])

#template = cv2.imread(needle_filename)
#template = cv2.imread(templates_dir + '1.tif',0)
#(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
# display the  image and template to our screen 
#cv2.imshow("Image", image)
#cv2.imshow("Template", template)



# convert both the image and template to grayscale
imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# perform template matching
print("[INFO] performing template matching...")
for template in templates:
    (tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
    templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(imageGray, templateGray,
                               cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)



# find all locations in the result map where the matched value is
# greater than the threshold, then clone our original image so we
# can draw on it
(yCoords, xCoords) = np.where(result >= threshold)
clone = image.copy()
print("[INFO] {} matched locations *before* NMS".format(len(yCoords)))
# loop over our starting (x, y)-coordinates
for (x, y) in zip(xCoords, yCoords):
    # draw the bounding box on the image
    cv2.rectangle(clone, (x, y), (x + tW, y + tH),(255, 0, 0), 3)

# show our output image *before* applying non-maxima suppression
#cv2.imshow("Before NMS", clone)
#cv2.waitKey(0)


# initialize our list of rectangles
rects = []
locs = []
# loop over the starting (x, y)-coordinates again
for (x, y) in zip(xCoords, yCoords):
    # update our list of rectangles
    rects.append((x, y, x + tW, y + tH))
# apply non-maxima suppression to the rectangles
pick = non_max_suppression(np.array(rects))#
print("[INFO] {} matched locations *after* NMS".format(len(pick)))
# loop over the final bounding boxes
for (startX, startY, endX, endY) in pick:
    # draw the bounding box on the image
    location = (int(endX+(startX-endX)/2), int(endY+(startY-endY)/2))
    locs.append(location)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),(255, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.drawMarker(image, location, color=[0, 0, 0], thickness=1, 
                   markerType= cv2.MARKER_TILTED_CROSS, line_type=cv2.LINE_AA,
                   markerSize=9)
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("After NMS", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try template matching with an average pinprick as the template?  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: This is cross-posted here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/88669/33605 — please don’t cross-post, it duplicates information and effort from the community.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Very sorry, I was under the misapprehension it was a separate forum.

Comment: crossposting of any kind should be *declared* (crosslinking). being honest is better than not declaring.